# Retain scroll position on back in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to retain the scroll position on back button but the scroll position is going back to the 0,0
The code is as follows -

```
 <SearchListWrapper className="TestSL" ref={this.myRef}  onScroll={this.handleScrollPosition} >
```

```
    handleScrollPosition(e){

   sessionStorage.setItem("scrollPosition", this.myRef.current!.scrollTop.toString());
       };
```

```
async componentDidMount() {
        console.log("inside CDM")
        if(sessionStorage.getItem("scrollPosition"))
        {
            const scrollpos =Number(sessionStorage.getItem("scrollPosition"))

            this.myRef.current!.scrollTo(0,scrollpos)
          

        }
}
```

I tried the above code and expecting the values in session to be fixed and not change back to 0,0 on back button.

Comment: It would not be completely stupid if you were describe your problem once properly and not make copies of the question hoping that someone will solve the problem you are having and not one of the 4 ways it can be interpreted as.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you:

`example-child-scroll.jsx`

```
// This example will manage the scroll position for a DOM element.
// The key must be unique per managed element, as it is used as a key in a store
// when saving and restoring the position.
import React from 'react'
import ScrollManager from './ScrollManager'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ScrollManager scrollKey="some-list-key">
        {({ connectScrollTarget, ...props }) => 
          <div ref={connectScrollTarget} style={{ overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: 500 }}>
            If this div is unmounted and remounted, scroll position is restored.
          </div>
        }
      </ScrollManager>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`ScrollManager.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import requestAnimationFrame from 'raf'

export const memoryStore = {
  _data: new Map(),
  get(key) {
    if (!key) {
      return null
    }

    return this._data.get(key) || null
  },
  set(key, data) {
    if (!key) {
      return
    }
    return this._data.set(key, data)
  }
}

/**
 * Component that will save and restore Window scroll position.
 */
export default class ScrollPositionManager extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(...arguments)
    this.connectScrollTarget = this.connectScrollTarget.bind(this)
    this._target = window
  }

  connectScrollTarget(node) {
    this._target = node
  }

  restoreScrollPosition(pos) {
    pos = pos || this.props.scrollStore.get(this.props.scrollKey)
    if (this._target && pos) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        scroll(this._target, pos.x, pos.y)
      })
    }
  }

  saveScrollPosition(key) {
    if (this._target) {
      const pos = getScrollPosition(this._target)
      key = key || this.props.scrollKey
      this.props.scrollStore.set(key, pos)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.restoreScrollPosition()
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
    if (this.props.scrollKey !== nextProps.scrollKey) {
        this.saveScrollPosition()
    }
    return true;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.scrollKey !== prevProps.scrollKey) {
      this.restoreScrollPosition()
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.saveScrollPosition()
  }

  render() {
    const { children = null, ...props } = this.props
    return (
      children &&
      children({ ...props, connectScrollTarget: this.connectScrollTarget })
    )
  }
}

ScrollPositionManager.defaultProps = {
  scrollStore: memoryStore
}

function scroll(target, x, y) {
  if (target instanceof window.Window) {
    target.scrollTo(x, y)
  } else {
    target.scrollLeft = x
    target.scrollTop = y
  }
}

function getScrollPosition(target) {
  if (target instanceof window.Window) {
    return { x: target.scrollX, y: target.scrollY }
  }

  return { x: target.scrollLeft, y: target.scrollTop }
}
```

Comment: I am looking to scroll into an element and not window

Comment: I have provided another answer. It should work for your case.